# Calling dynamic SQL Server stored procedure - expects parameter which was not supplied

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call a stored procedure, the name of which is provided by looping through a table. The stored procedure is in another database.

However, I keep getting the message

> Procedure or function 'sp_KPI_People_Added_Count' expects parameter
>   '@Period', which was not supplied.

But it is being supplied.

I have set the statement and parameter definition to `NVarChar` and prefixed them with `N`. I've also tried this on the parameters themselves but apparently that's not required.

All the print output is as expected and if I call an execute with the text, it works fine.

So I'm stuck.  Any pointers would be warmly welcomed.

Thanks,

Chris.

```
Declare @KPI_Value Decimal(14,4)
Declare @StoredProcedure NVarChar(200)
Declare @Periodic Char(1)
Declare @ExecSql NVarChar(200)
Declare @ParameterDefinition AS NVarChar(200)

Declare KPI_Cursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    SELECT SProc, Periodic from KPI where Section = 2
    FOR UPDATE OF Current_Value

Open KPI_Cursor

Fetch Next From KPI_Cursor into @StoredProcedure, @Periodic
Declare @Required_Period VARCHAR(5)
SET @Required_Period='MTD'

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
Set @KPI_Value = 0  -- Have tried with and without this

    If @Periodic = 'Z' BEGIN
        SET @ExecSQL = N'Prod.dbo.' + @StoredProcedure;
        /* Specify Parameter Format */
        SET @ParameterDefinition =  N'@Period VarChar(5), @Result_Type VarChar(10), @Result Decimal(14,4) OUTPUT';
        /* Execute Transact-SQL String */
        print @ExecSQL
        print @ParameterDefinition
        print @Required_Period
        print @KPI_Value
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @ExecSQL, @ParameterDefinition, @Required_Period, 'Result', @KPI_Value Output 
    END

    Fetch Next from KPI_Cursor into @StoredProcedure, @Periodic
END

Close KPI_Cursor
Deallocate KPI_Cursor
```

The stored procedures have parameters as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_KPI_People_Added_Count] 
    @Period VarChar(5),     -- MTD or YTD
    @Result_Type VarChar(10),   -- Summary, Result or Detail
    @Result Decimal(14,4) OUTPUT    -- The returned result
AS
....
```

The output is as follows:

> Prod.dbo.sp_KPI_People_Added_Count
>   @Period VarChar(5), @Result_Type VarChar(10), @Result Decimal(14,4) OUTPUT
>   MTD
>   0.0000
>   Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure sp_KPI_Cust_Added_Count, Line 0
>   Procedure or function 'sp_KPI_People_Added_Count' expects parameter '@Period', which was not supplied.

Comment: You know you don't need sp_executesql in this case?

Comment: Not good idea to name the procedure starting with sp_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative way...

[EXEC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) has the little used form `EXEC @module_name_var`

So you can do this

```
If @Periodic = 'Z' BEGIN
    SET @module_name_var = N'Prod.dbo.' + @StoredProcedure;
    EXEC @module_name_var @Required_Period, 'Result', @KPI_Value Output 
END
```

One observation about your original code...

Use `N'Result'` for the 2nd parameter. [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) says (my bold)

> [ @param1= ] 'value1'
>
> Is a value for the first parameter that is defined in the parameter string. The value can be a **Unicode constant** or a Unicode variable. There must be a parameter value supplied for every parameter included in stmt.

Comment: The change to the Declare didn't help but using just Exec as above did. Thats great and thank you, but I can't see why the other form didn't work.

Comment: @Chris: I don't know why either. I wonder if it because you call a stored proc rather than execute simple DML